# Is it possible to get the game object of the input field I am typing into in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene with multiple input fields in my unity app and I would like to update some variables dynamically as the user types into the input fields. I would like to be able to only update the variable corresponding to the updated input field (not having to loop through all of the input fields in the scene and set all variables). Is there a way to get the game object of the input field I am currently typing into? I have a function that I set as the OnValueChanged function in the input fields, but I only log the current value of the field right now:
```
public void InputUpdate(string input) {
  Debug.Log(input);
}
```
The setup in the editor:

[![Editor setup][1]][1]

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why, but the question loads without any formatting and missing "Hello" at the beginning of the question, I tried to edit it and once I type anything while editing, it fixes the formatting, but then it still loads weirdly on the question page. Not sure how to fix it, hope it is usable like this (the main part is the explanation).
Here is a link to an image that shows how the question is supposed to look like: https://imgur.com/uWFVQTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the specific gameObject per input field, I would consider assigning the callback in code. Something along the lines of:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<InputField> yourInputFields = new List<InputField>();

    public void Start()
    {
        foreach (InputField input in yourInputFields)
            input.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { Test(input.text, input.gameObject); });
    }


    public void Test(string str, GameObject go = null)
    {
        Debug.Log(go.name + " " + str);
    }
}
```

The function `Test` will now get called with the specific gameObject assigned in `Start`, which is tied to the specific `InputField` `onValueChange`. Just assign each `InputField` you want to use this callback in the inspector by dragging them into the exposed list.